# Parsing N letters after a symbol from a dataframe of strings

Tags: r, substring

I have a dataframe of strings that I want to remove all the letters following a `$` symbol. I only want the letters until there is a space, special character other than `/`, or number

```
strings <- data.frame("strings"=c("String test $ABCD","$BGI test",  
"super weird $nabc test","$500 giveway","another $Abc/a test"))
```

I have been able to figure it out for all strings that start with `$` using `grepl("^\\$",strings)` but I am missing the strings where `$` is in middle of string for example. Also, want to remove any strings that are `$0:9`

output goal is:

```
ABCD
BGI
nabc
Abc/a
```

so trying to find a way to use grepl or something similar that finds the `$` and keeps all `characters` until there is a `space`,`number`,or `special character` other than `/`

If the `/` is the least important, but if can figure out a way to incorporate all that'd be great! Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to _remove_ those characters or extract only those characters/? Your proposed output looks like you want to extract those strings (except that you missed the $500)

Comment: I want to extract them from a dataframe - will use the extraction to create a new dataframe that I will work off of

The exclusion of $500 was intentional, I only want extract if first character is letter that follow the `$`

Comment: OK,  will change my answer.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract(strings$strings, '\\$[A-Za-z]+')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsub(".*\\$([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\/]*).*", "\\1", 
    strings$strings[grepl("\\$[a-zA-Z]", strings$strings)], perl=TRUE)
[1] "ABCD"  "BGI"   "nabc"  "Abc/a"
```

Update: OP asked to *not* include / and characters after.  That can be accomplished with:

```
gsub(".*\\$([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*).*", "\\1", 
       strings$strings[grepl("\\$[a-zA-Z]", strings$strings)], perl=TRUE)
[1] "ABCD" "BGI"  "nabc" "Abc"
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible thank you! One issue with it is that it is still keeps the string following `/` symbols. I reviewed the results and actually makes total sense to just keep the characters (so new last result would be `Abc` instead of `Abc/a`.

Comment: Oh,  You want to stop at /?     I will change my answer.

Comment: yeah, apologies once I reviewed the results it made most sense to only keep the letters

Comment: Thanks again - it is still keeping the characters following \ symbol in both answers, can you please advise?

Comment: Odd. It is working for me. Did you cut and paste the code from the (second) answer? Also you say the characters following \ but there is no \ in the example. Do you mean /?

Comment: Thanks G5W, you have been hugely helpful and I realize I am completely shifting from my original question, but only was able to realize what I needed once your solution worked for me.  I am actually hoping to subset from a larger dataset based on if a string in the string column contains a `$`, then from there I want to remove all the other text and just keep what you showed me above. Would this be possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want the subset with $ followed by a letter or just keep anything with a $?

Comment: I'm saying let say there are more rows in the string column, but they don't contain a `$` at all. I want to subset the dataframe to only include rows that have a `$` in the string, and then extract the letters following the `$` as you have shown me above. Make snese?

Comment: In the original question,  you wanted $ followed by a letter. Do you want all rows with a $ or only those with $ followed by letter.  If you want all rows with $   what should be returned when it is $ followed by something other than a letter?

Comment: What I have so far is not quite working  `df[which[grepl(".*\\$([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\/]*).*",df$string_column)), ]`

Comment: Only rows with $ followed by letter please